# how to select elements by name with serial

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to select elements with wildcard?

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[0]" class="" value="505517254641">
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[1]" class="" value="505517254642">
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[2]" class="" value="505517254643">
```

**and JavaScript code to select elements**

```
let o= document.querySelectorAll("[name='variable_ebay_ean[(*)]']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reach it using the "[Starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)" selector.

```js
let o= document.querySelectorAll("[name^='variable_ebay_ean']");
```

```js
let o = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='variable_ebay_ean']");
console.log(o);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[0]" class="" value="505517254641">
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[1]" class="" value="505517254642">
<input type="text" name="variable_ebay_ean[2]" class="" value="505517254643">
```